# List of characters managed by a collation

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, collation, character-set

I'm migrating to MySQL 8.0.33. We are changing character set to utf8mb4.
For collation, I'm wondering among different options.

I'm looking for documentation to review the list of characters that are "covered", "managed" or "included" in a collation.
For example, I don't know if I can have some troubles with À in a WHERE clause comparison in some collation. So, I'd like to look for if À is covered or managed by a collation.

Other way to make the question. I found this link, but it's old for me:
https://collation-charts.org/mysql60/mysql604.utf8_spanish_ci.html

I'd like to find something like this, or a file in MySQL installation, or documentation... To check if a character is managed by a collation.
And I'd like to check "*xxx* collation manages 200 characters and *zzz* collation manages 500 characters".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "So, I'd like to look for if À is covered or managed by a collation."? Could you expand on this please?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in the internals, but looking through the MySQL source I believe the utf8mb4 collations are implemented as compiled code. These collations are derived from data in the MySQL source in [strings/uca_data.h](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/trunk/strings/uca_data.h)

From what I understand from the code, all characters are supported. There are 256 pages, and 256 characters in each page. That covers the 4-byte range of characters in utf8mb4.

Answer (score 1):

`CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` in an "encoding".  It handles all characters defined by Unicode 9.0.0.

There are many `COLLATIONs`.  For example, `utf8mb4_icelandic_ci` orders characters in a way specific to Iceland.  For general use, use `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`.

https://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8mb4_collations.html lists letter-like characters handled by that somewhat old version of 8.0.17.  There have been newer collations since then.

Do you need `ae = æ`?  Or maybe `a < æ`, as if `æ` were a letter that sorts between `a` and `b`?

`À` is handled by the character set, and for *most* collations with names containing `_ai_`, it is treated as equal to `A`.

If you need a collation for Hungarian, there seems to be a dispute as to whether `A` < `Á`.

That Spanish chart is old, and limited.  But probably still valid for that one collation.  There are two, slightly different, collations for Spanish.  I think `ll` and `ch` are the only differences between them.  utf8mb4_spanish2_ci treats them as separate letters (between `l` and `m` for `ll` and between `c` and `d` for `ch`); utf8mb4_spanish_ci does not.

`utf8mb3` is limited to UTF-8 characters represented in 3 bytes; `utf8mb4` covers characters of up to 4 bytes.  Unicode has yet defined no 5-byte characters.  `utf8` is currently a synonym for `utf8mb3`, but is slated to be a synonym for `utf8mb4` in a future MySQL release.  Avoid `utf8`; I predict there will be chaos when the change occurs.

Newer collations may act differently than old ones.  For example, Emoji started as all comparing equal.  Later they became different.